# Eliminar puntos cercanos/duplicados mediante un buffer en R

Tags: r, eliminar-duplicados

tengo una base de datos con puntos georreferenciados (spatialpointsdataframe) que he recopilado, habían duplicados para una mismo sitio, los cuales elimine así:

```
   BD_SD <- BDTOTAL[which(!duplicated(BDTOTAL@coords)), ]
```

pero tras una revisión minuciosa me di cuenta que algunos duplicados no fueron eliminados ya que las coordenadas no eran idénticas sino que muy cercanas (incluso por decimales), entonces lo que necesito conservar solo uno de los varios puntos que podrían estar p.ej distanciados a menos de 15 metros, ¿cual seria la forma de hacer funcionar esto?

el buffer para los puntos lo he creado de la siguiente forma, aunque reproyectar es necesario ya que he manejado coordenadas geográficas decimales previamente:

```
BD_SD <- spTransform(BD_SD, CRSobj = '+proj=tmerc')
library(rgeos)
ids <- 1:nrow(BD_SD)
bp <- gBuffer(BD_SD, 15, byid=T, id= ids)
```

pero en este punto ya no he podido avanzar, ademas lamentablemente no puedo aportar un conjunto de datos para el ejercicio.

quedo atento a sus aportes y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El enfoque por buffers está bien si tienes los puntos iniciales que consideras que no son duplicados. Pero entiendo que esta no es la situación, por lo que si simplemente quieres eliminar puntos cercanos (sin importar cual de ellos seleccionas) yo te propondria el siguiente código.

Uso la libreria `sf` ya que a dia de hoy es prácticamente el estandar en manejor de datos espaciales, pero convertir datos entre `sf` y `sp` es muy sencillo (`sf::st_as_sf()` para ir de `sp` a `sf` y `as(x, "Spatial")` de `sf` a `sp`).

Empiezo creando unos datos de ejemplo:

```r
# trabajo con sf
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# creo dos puntos

a <- data.frame(
  x = c("a", "b"),
  name = c("init", "init"),
  lon = c(0.31345, 1.56789),
  lat = c(32, 32)
)
# set de puntos duplicados con un ligero factor
b <- a
b$lon <- b$lon + 0.00005

# dataset a formato espacial con ESPG:4326
bd <- st_as_sf(rbind(a, b),
  coords = c("lon", "lat"),
  crs = 4326
)

bd
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.31345 ymin: 32 xmax: 1.56794 ymax: 32
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   x name           geometry
#> 1 a init POINT (0.31345 32)
#> 2 b init POINT (1.56789 32)
#> 3 a init  POINT (0.3135 32)
#> 4 b init POINT (1.56794 32)
```

Como ves, los puntos de las filas 3 y 4 son muy cercanos a los puntos de las filas 1 y 2 por construcción.

Ahora podemos usar la matriz de distancias para ver cómo de lejos están los puntos
entre si

```r
# Comprobamos la matriz de distancias
m <- st_distance(bd)

m
#> Units: [m]
#>              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
#> [1,]      0.00000 118291.51548      4.71494 118296.23034
#> [2,] 118291.51548      0.00000 118286.80062      4.71494
#> [3,]      4.71494 118286.80062      0.00000 118291.51548
#> [4,] 118296.23034      4.71494 118291.51548      0.00000
```

La matriz nos dice que los puntos 3 y 4 están a menos de 5 metros de los puntos 1 y 2.

A partir de aqui, podemos seguir un flujo de trabajo según el tidyverse para identificar los puntos a eliminar:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.3

# Pasamos la matriz a formato largo
df <- as_tibble(m) %>%
  mutate(id1 = 1:nrow(bd)) %>%
  pivot_longer(1:4,
    names_to = "id2",
    values_to = "distance"
  ) %>%
  mutate(id2 = as.integer(gsub("V", "", id2)))

df
#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#>      id1   id2  distance
#>    <int> <int>       [m]
#>  1     1     1      0   
#>  2     1     2 118292.  
#>  3     1     3      4.71
#>  4     1     4 118296.  
#>  5     2     1 118292.  
#>  6     2     2      0   
#>  7     2     3 118287.  
#>  8     2     4      4.71
#>  9     3     1      4.71
#> 10     3     2 118287.  
#> 11     3     3      0   
#> 12     3     4 118292.  
#> 13     4     1 118296.  
#> 14     4     2      4.71
#> 15     4     3 118292.  
#> 16     4     4      0
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que `st_distance()` da los resultados en una clase de objectos definida como `units`, que proporciona el paquete del mismo nombre.

Lo ultimo es quitar los elementos de la diagonal (distancia 0) y los
de la diagonal superior para evitar relaciones duplicadas (por ejemplo, 1 a 3 y 3 a 1 tienen la misma distancia), y seleccionar las filas a eliminar:

```r
index_dups <- df %>%
  filter(
    # Esto selecciona las distancias por debajo de la diagonal
    id1 < id2,
    # Filtramos por puntos a menos de 15 metros, usando units
    distance < units::set_units(15, "m")
  ) %>%
  select(id2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pull()


index_dups
#> [1] 3 4

# Por ultimo eliminamos los duplicados del data frame

bd2 <- bd[-index_dups, ]

bd2
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.31345 ymin: 32 xmax: 1.56789 ymax: 32
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   x name           geometry
#> 1 a init POINT (0.31345 32)
#> 2 b init POINT (1.56789 32)
```

Si necesitas pasarlo a `sp`:

```r
# A sp
bd2_sp <- as(bd2, "Spatial")
class(bd2_sp)
#> [1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

bd2_sp
#>     coordinates x name
#> 1 (0.31345, 32) a init
#> 2 (1.56789, 32) b init
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>